# set variable from task only when task is called

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I've defined a task called debug that should set the applicationDefaultJvmArgs of the application plugin so that spring-boot will halt and wait for the debugger.

I would like to use this task in combination with another task I have defined called local which sets a spring.profiles.active variable.

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

dependencies {
    compile group: "org.apache.camel", name: "camel-netty4-http", version: camelVersion
    compile group: "org.apache.camel", name: "camel-spring-boot", version: camelVersion
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter", version: "1.2.1.RELEASE"
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foobar'
    user = 'foo'
    password = 'bar'
}

task local {
    tasks.withType(org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask) {
        systemProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'local')
    }
}

task debug << {
    project.ext {
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
                "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I call gradle using `gradle local debug` the debug the applicationDefaultJvmArgs are set but when I call `gralde local` they are also set ?

I've tried experimenting with

```
task debug << { ...
```

but that wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Where is applicationDefaultJvmArgs defined? Can you provide the full code for your build script? 
I believe that the next piece of code should do the job:

```
task debug << {
    project.ext {
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
            "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"    
        ]
    }
}
```

The changes:

1. Assigning applicationDefaultJvmArgs as part of the debug task action (rather than a configuration)
2. Defining applicationDefaultJvmArgs as a project property

Comment: applicationDefaultJvmArgs is defined in the application plugin: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html
The proposed solution doesn't work. I've also updated the code sample given.

Comment: Strange since I verified the proposed solution with a simple project which takes no dependencies on the spring-boot and flyway plugins. Just to validate your assumption, can you add the following task `task printJvmArgs << { println applicationDefaultJvmArgs }` and add a call to it for both cases (i.e. first call `gradle local debug printJvmArgs` and then `gradle local printJvmArgs`)?